How to pass a "tuple" into UseMutationOption third generic?
I want to write mutationFn: ( a, b ) => testFn(a, b) in useTest2 but I do not know what type I should provide to the third generic of UseMutationOptions.
My current solution is passing the params in object form (useTest)
Thanks
  const testFn=async (a:string, b:string[])=>{return 1}

  type MutationFnParams={
    a:string,
    b:string[]
  }

  export const useTest = (
    options?: UseMutationOptions<number, Error, MutationFnParams>,
  ) =>
    useMutation({
      mutationFn: ({ a, b }: MutationFnParams) => testFn(a, b),
      ...options,
    });
  

    export const useTest2 = (
      options?: UseMutationOptions<number, Error, ??>,
    ) =>
      useMutation({
        mutationFn: ( a:string, b:string[] ) => testFn(a, b),
        ...options,
      });
    


If you're trying to get the parameter type of a function, try the utility type Parameters<Type> - Parameters<typeof testFn>, which would be the tuple type [a: string, b: string[]]
Also, change the TData type to the corresponding return type from function testFn using ReturnType<Type> - ReturnType<typeof testFn>.
export const useTest2 = (
  options?: UseMutationOptions<ReturnType<typeof testFn>, Error, Parameters<typeof testFn>>,
) => useMutation({
  mutationFn: (a, b) => testFn(a, b),
  ...options,
});


tried this, but got this error
Type '(a: string, b: string[]) => Promise' is not assignable to type 'MutationFunction<number, [a: string, b: string[]]>'

Because the function testFn is an async function which actually returns a Promise<number> but not number, you can also get the correct return type using ReturnType<typeof testFn> which I have shown in my updated answer.
